# SharePoint list - Email button

Tags: json, list, email, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

This code makes that the outlook windows opens automatically when we press the "email" button and takes the email that has been saved in the "Kontakt" Field. We need to complete this code so when we press the button it automatically takes the subject for an email saved in another field. Is it possible with this JSON code?

```
{
  "_comment": "A button to send an email",
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "ms-fontColor-black ms-fontColor-white--hover",
    "title": "Send Email",
    "href": "='mailto:' + [$Kontakt.email]",
    "target": "_blank"
  },
  "style": {
    "border": "none",
    "cursor": "pointer",
    "background-color": "transparent"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "attributes": {
        "class": "ms-bgColor-greenLight ms-bgColor-green--hover ms-fontColor-black ms-fontColor-white--hover"
      },
      "style": {
        "font-size": "16px",
        "font-family": "arial",
        "border": "1px solid Black",
        "border-radius": "7px",
        "padding": "3px 5px 3px 5px",
        "box-shadow": "2px 2px #999"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "attributes": {
            "iconName": "Mail"
          },
          "style": {
            "display": "=if('Mail' != '','inline-block','none')",
            "vertical-align": "middle",
            "padding-right": "5px"
          }       
        },
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "txtContent": "=if('' != '',' EMAIL',' EMAIL')",
          "style": {
            "display": "inline-block",
            "font-family": "arial",
            "vertical-align": "middle"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is the name and data/column type of another field you want to include in subject?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add to that to your href value.

Try something like:

```
"href": "='mailto:' + [$Kontakt.email] + '?subject=' + [$Subject]"
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly, when i add this line of code the button disappears from the sharepoint and when i delete this line it appears again...

Comment: In my example I have created a single line of text column called Subject (both internal and displayName) and included it in the view. The rest of the json is from your code snippet. I only updated the href value in the json to include the subject parameter :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have another field named `EmailSubject` with column type as single line of text or multiple lines,

You can change `href` property in your JSON like:

```
"href": "='mailto:' + [$Kontakt.email] + '?subject=' + [$EmailSubject]",
```

Where `EmailSubject` is the internal name of your column. You can get the exact internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

For more information, check this Microsoft official documentation: [Add an email action button to a field (advanced)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#add-an-action-button-to-a-field-advanced)

Check this documentation for supported properties inside `mailto`: [How to Create Mailto Links](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-create-mailto-links.html)

---

**Update**:

Use this complete JSON:

```
{
  "_comment": "A button to send an email",
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "ms-fontColor-black ms-fontColor-white--hover",
    "title": "Send Email",
    "href": "='mailto:' + [$Kontakt.email] + '?subject=' + [$EmailSubject]",
    "target": "_blank"
  },
  "style": {
    "border": "none",
    "cursor": "pointer",
    "background-color": "transparent"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "attributes": {
        "class": "ms-bgColor-greenLight ms-bgColor-green--hover ms-fontColor-black ms-fontColor-white--hover"
      },
      "style": {
        "font-size": "16px",
        "font-family": "arial",
        "border": "1px solid Black",
        "border-radius": "7px",
        "padding": "3px 5px 3px 5px",
        "box-shadow": "2px 2px #999"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "attributes": {
            "iconName": "Mail"
          },
          "style": {
            "display": "=if('Mail' != '','inline-block','none')",
            "vertical-align": "middle",
            "padding-right": "5px"
          }       
        },
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "txtContent": "=if('' != '',' EMAIL',' EMAIL')",
          "style": {
            "display": "inline-block",
            "font-family": "arial",
            "vertical-align": "middle"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Exactly, when i add this line of code the button disappears from the sharepoint and when i delete this line it appears again...

Comment: Are you using correct internal name of subject column? Check updated answer and use complete JSON given in answer.